# View whitespace in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, whitespace

After Jeph most recent post: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001310.html, I thought to myself it would be fun to see if any of my code has those trailing whitespaces.

So I open Visual Studio, go to settings and I can't find an option to make this visible.

Is this possible in VS2008?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`CTRL+R`, `CTRL+W` will turn on whitespace.

Answer (score 5):

Edit, Advanced, View White space

https://blogs.msdn.com/saraford/archive/2005/03/21/399811.aspx

http://scottcate.com/Tricks/003/